# После перезагрузки пропадают машины в сети. В чём может быть дело?

Tags: linux, сеть

В общем, ситуация такая. Есть оптика, к ней подключен роутер, к нему кабелем подключены старый ноутбук в роли домашней файлопомойки (Ubuntu Server 14.04.5) и PC (Xubuntu 16.04.1), также роутер раздаёт WiFi. DHCP включён. Всё работает, но только до первой перезагрузки одной из машин подключённых по кабелю, т.е если перезагружу например файлопомойку, то с PC она никоим образом не видна (не пингуется, по SSH не подключается и т.п.,). Однако если переключится на WiFi, то таких проблем не наблюдается, всё пингуется, по SSH подключается. В чём может быть дело ?

Comment: если подобное происходит зеркально с обоими компьютерами, то очевидно, что первый кандидат в виновники — маршрутизатор (неполадки либо некорректные настройки).

Comment: закрывающие, кто Вам сказал, что проблема решена?